# custom iOS gesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am new to iOS/objective-C and I wanted to know how to build custom gestures. In particular, if a user taps the top right of the screen and slides his/her finger down the edge of the device to the bottom (same gesture for the left hand side). I read through this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2

But I guess I am having trouble figuring out how to apply it to my specific case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass is a bit involved to do in a solid way. I very much recommend watching the WWDC2010 videos on the subject `Session 120 - Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers` & `Session 121 - Advanced Gesture Recognition`. They are thorough and well done.

But for a very simple example, based on your question, I created a very simple gesture recognizer that fires when a user touches the upper left quadrant of the attached view and slides their finger down to the lower right quadrant of the attached view and picks up their finger, without sliding to the left side of the attached view.

`RightSlidedown.h:`

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h> // This import is essential
@interface RightSlidedown : UIGestureRecognizer
@end
```

`RightSlidedown.m`

```
#import "RightSlidedown.h"
@implementation RightSlidedown
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action{
    if ((self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action])){
        // so simple there's no setup
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch locationInView:self.view].x < CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    else if ([touch locationInView:self.view].y > CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch locationInView:self.view].x < CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch locationInView:self.view].x < CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    else if ([touch locationInView:self.view].y < CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
    else {
            // setting the state to recognized fires the target/action pair of the recognizer
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized; 
    }
}
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}
-(void)reset{
    // so simple there's no reset
}
@end
```

So basically the gesture recognizer gets what seems like the standard touch events. (They're not, but they act that way). As you respond to the movements you change the `state` property of your gesture recognizer.

There are two basic types of recognizers, "Discrete" (think tap gesture) and "Continuous" (think pan gesture). Both types automatically start in `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible` in the beginning.

For a "Discrete" type, like this one, your goal is to get to state `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` as soon as possible.

The ideal usage of this example would be to add the `RightSlidedown` gesture recognizer to the main view of a new "Single View Application" in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[RightSlidedown alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSlide:)]];
```

Then a simple action method is all that's required, like so:

```
-(void)rightSlide:(RightSlidedown *)rsd{
    NSLog(@"right slide");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very complete response. I ran into two issues:

1) For whatever reason, whenever I do the gesture, I never make it to the "touches ended" function. I am wondering if there is some sort of time limit in which you have to slide your finger down the whole screen.

2) I currently have another long press gesture recognizer on my view (just push and hold handler). How do I distinguish between these two gestures?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Also 1) This gesture recognizer imposes no time limit. Not getting to `touchesEnded:` is normal if the recognizer fails (failure likely from long press recognizing). 2)The gesture recognizers distinguish themselves by calling their associated action methods.

Comment: Okay, so I identified the problem I was having with regards to touchesEnded:. I want to use this sliding gesture on top of a table view. It works fine on a normal view, but it doesn't execute properly on top of a table view.

Comment: Coordinating multiple gesture recognizers is tricky enough, the dance involves implementations of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods and  callings of `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`. But creating your first recognizer to use with the multiple recognizers that apple uses in a table view will be tricky. Seriously, try this `NSLog(@"%@",self.tableView.gestureRecognizers);` in a `UITableViewController` subclass and see how many odd recognizers there are to deal with.

Comment: I guess the issue is that when I do this gesture the table view thinks that I am scrolling down. That is certainly okay, but it masks this gesture from firing. Is there not an easy way to make both of them compatible?

Comment: @user1120008 This is far from the topic of how in general to create a gesture recognizer, which I think has been answered. But on an advice note, when people drag up or down on a `UITableView` they generally expect the table to scroll. If other behaviors that are counter-intuitive to the user happen this will likely result in frustration. If you need to implement a behavior contrary to normal tableview behavior, then consider just putting a slim control to either side of the tableview, that way the user will know there is a difference to this area.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by seeing either positive or negative delta in the x and y axis of the touch. for instance, a check mark gesture (√) will be a negative delta followed by a positive delta in the y while there is always a negative delta with the x and the touch ends at a lower height than where it started. Add more fingers you add more checks.

Pseudocode:

```
bool firstStroke, secondStroke, motion, override;
while (touchdown){
if (yDelta < 0){firstStroke = TRUE;}
if (firstStroke && yDelta > 0){secondStroke = TRUE;}
if (xDelta < 0){motion = TRUE;}
if (xDelta > 0 || (firstStroke && secondStroke && yDelta < 0)){override = TRUE;}
}
if (firstStroke && secondStroke && motion && start.y > end.y && !override){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

The while command means that while the touch is down, check for 3 things:

-If the touch has moved down

-If after the touch has moved down that it has moved up again

-If the touch is moving a right to left

The forth check is to see if the touch ever moved left to right or if after the gesture moved down after the gesture has been finished.

After the touch is finished, there is one more check to see if the gesture moved correctly, if the points started and ended in the correct places and if the gesture moved in an incorrect motion (override).

Hope that helps.