# Extend Gesture Length

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, extend

I've come across a problem to which the simplest solution would be to extend the length of a UIGestureRecognizer. What I mean is that I need the iOS device to still believe the user has their finger on the screen for about 0.1 seconds after they release it. I need the device to think that the finger is in the exact same position for the 0.1 seconds as it was when the user released this.
Any help as to weather this is possible would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!!!

EDIT:
Sorry for the late reply, I've been really busy with work.

To elaborate, I'm using a set of classes made by Alan Quartermain called AQGridView. It's a class that strongly resembles UITableView; however, it displays data in a grid instead of a list. There appears to be a bug where (if I understand correctly, and I may very well not) the data of the grid is reloaded before the delegate method, that is called when a user ends a UIGestureRecognizer, finishes if the user releases their finger while dragging a cell (from one grid index to another) very quickly. This causes a graphical glitch (which can be recreated in the springboard example that comes with the class set) where the dragging cell appears to settle one cell before or after it's appropriate location, and then quickly jumps to it's proper location. I believe this is because there is a brief period, when the user releases their finger, where the grids count is -1 of what it is when the cell settles.
This is a poor explanation of the problem, but the best I could come up with. As well, I'm a relatively new developer and could be way off on the cause of the problem. That is why I believe the most appropriate fix would be to extend the gesture length by a very small amount. If anyone wants to take a look at the AQGridView classes (https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/) I would really appreciate it! But if possible a simpler fix would just be to simulate the touch that the user inputed right before they released their finger so that the desired animation occurs.

Comment: If you describe what the gesture does, and what you want to do during or after the 0.1 seconds, we might be able to give you better help.

Comment: Why does it need to believe their finger is still there? Can you solve the problem by adding a delay instead? For example by using `dispatch_after` or `performSelector:afterDelay:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `touchesEnded` delegate method, start timer for 0.1 second and perform your `selector`.

You can even, subclass UIGestureRecogniser and implement your own gestures, Check the first answer of this question.

See : [custom iOS gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345718/custom-ios-gesture)